# Strange Pointer behavior in while loop

Tags: c, pointers, hash, while-loop, memory-address

Hello I insert some values into an hash table(the implemented hash table is well tested and works)
I read in a file with fscanf and store the values of the string and the float in variables.

The text file looks like this:

```
die 0.000000
laun -4.102468
des -7.952615
verliebt -6.080813
ein -8.645762
schaferspiel -4.315029
in -8.645762
vers -5.755391
und -8.645762
akt -3.909564
person -8.645762
egl -8.645762
```

The read in works like this:

```
//scan text for scheme WORDSTEM PROBABLITIY
r = fscanf(text, "%s %f\n", wordstem, &prob);
//doing some pointer madness!!!
pProb = &prob;
float PpProb = *pProb;
float *PPpProb = &PpProb;
char *cpStr = strdup(wordstem);
hashtable_access(wordHash, cpStr,PPpProb); //insert into hashtable_t
while (r != EOF){
    float prob1;
    r = fscanf(text, "%s %f\n", wordstem, &prob1);
    //printf("%f",prob1);
    char *cpStr1 = strdup(wordstem);
    float a = 0;
    float *PpProb1 = &a;
    float *pProb1 = &prob1;
    *PpProb1 = *pProb1;
    hashtable_access(wordHash, cpStr1,PpProb1);
    pProb1 = NULL;
    //do till EOF
}
float *pHashProb = (float *)hashtable_access(wordHash, "schaferspiel", NULL);
float hashProb = *pHashProb;
printf("%f\n",hashProb);
```

The problem is that the hash returns for the first entry "die" the correct value but schaferspiel and every other key after the first returns always the last value.

The hash table requires to save pointers. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because i think I copied the value of prob1.

Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code (e.g., I don't understand why you are doing one insert prior to the loop but the rest in the loop), but I think the main problem is that you are using the same pointer to the float over and over in the hash table.  Try something like this:

```
float prob;
float *probCopy;

//scan text for scheme WORDSTEM PROBABLITIY
r = fscanf(text, "%s %f\n", wordstem, &prob);
probCopy = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
*probCopy = prob;
char *cpStr = strdup(wordstem);
hashtable_access(wordHash, cpStr, probCopy); //insert into hashtable_t
while (r != EOF) {
    float prob1;
    r = fscanf(text, "%s %f\n", wordstem, &prob1);
    probCopy = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float));
    *probCopy = prob1;
    char *cpStr1 = strdup(wordstem);
    hashtable_access(wordHash, cpStr1, probCopy);
    //do till EOF
}
float *pHashProb = (float *)hashtable_access(wordHash, "schaferspiel", NULL);
float hashProb = *pHashProb;
printf("%f\n",hashProb);
```

Note:  You should be aware that everything you put into the hash table will potentially "leak" unless the hash table cleans up the memory pointed to by its elements (or you explicitly do that yourself elsewhere).

Comment: WOW! This works like a charm! Spend hours for fixing it! Thank you very much!